# Hyperlinks with underscores in markdown Overleaf

Tags: markdown, hyperlink

I am using markdown from within Overleaf and would like to have hyperlinks written in markdown `[text](url)` to be displayed as hyperref-hyperlink similar to `\href{url}{text}`command. I followed the [suggestions given in Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Articles/How_to_write_in_Markdown_on_Overleaf) for rendering the markdown elements but it does not work for my particular links with underscores. Here is an example:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[footnotes,definitionLists,hashEnumerators,smartEllipses, hybrid]{markdown}
\markdownSetup{
renderers={
  link = {\href{#2}{#1}}
}}

\begin{document}

\begin{markdown}
- [genal patch](http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/HAO_0000373)
\end{markdown}

\end{document}
```

The URL that is displayed in the rendered pdf file is `http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/HAO_%7B%7D0000373` instead of `http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/HAO_0000373`.

Rendering the markdown links as footnotes works fine. Links without underscores are ok too. Also, `\href{url}{text}` correctly displays links outside the markdown environment.

I tried various options including escaping the underscores as `\_` but it does not work.

Can anyone tell me how to render underscores correctly in markdown links? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Your example doesn't compile.

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer, I've corrected it.

Comment: try with `link = {\href{#3}{#1}}`,

Comment: Great! It works! Thanks @UlrikeFischer !

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Happy New Year, If possible, can you make your comment into answer? Please

Answer (score 0):

I think the overleaf instruction is wrong. `#2` is the "the fully escaped uri that can be directly typeset" while `#3` is the "raw uri that can be used outside typesetting".

I didn't test if markdown can handle all types of url's correctly here (e.g. with  % or # in it) but for your underscore it works if you use `#3` (I removed the inputenc package as utf8 is the default since four years anyway):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[footnotes,definitionLists,hashEnumerators,smartEllipses, hybrid]{markdown}
\markdownSetup{
renderers={
  link = {\href{#3}{#1}}
}}

\begin{document}

\begin{markdown}
- [genal patch](http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/HAO_0000373)
\end{markdown}

\end{document}
```